# Get user message id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables in my DB: `users(id, pass, email)` and `messages(id, ownerid, text)`

I want to allow each user to edit his own message(via ajax, but that doesn't matter right now).

The question is, after accessing all of an user's message

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare( "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ownerid=:ownerid " );
//bind
$data = array( 'ownerid' => $_SESSION['id'] );
//exec
$STH->execute( $data );

while ( $results = $STH->fetch() ) {

    echo $results['text'];
}
```

I want to display them in editable textfields. The problem is that on clicking a certain textfield, how can I get the `id` of the message? I was thinking about including it in the html output, but that is not the most secure option.

Comment: You could use the MD5 hash of the id.

Comment: But where should I store it? In the message div? Isn't md5 unsafe, as well?

Comment: Ehm, displaying the id of the message is not really a problem concerning security imo. If you look at the html code of SO, you'll see it's full of id's too.

Comment: md5 is unsafe, certainly as you'll md5 the id's. Rainbowtables have cracked a trillion of numbers.

Comment: Then how do I get the id after I display it?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc You decide where to store it, e.g. in a custom `data-` attribute. MD5 is safe enough to store client-side; on server-side you will compare it to a fresh calculated MD5 hash of that id.

Comment: That's your choice. If a user clicks 'edit', you could issue a GET-request. (for example). Why are you concerned with displaying the id of a comment? Whenever a user updates, you just check again if it's his comment. No need to oversecure.

Comment: Can't they modify the html id, and my GET request will get an id of a message they don't own?

Comment: Yes. That's why you check if it's a valid user when you receive the GET-request. You do something like: `SELECT ownerid FROM messages WHERE id = $_GET['id']`. And check if ownerid is thesame as the logged in user. Also, make sure you protect yourself from mysql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a secure option. When a user edit's his comment, you issue a GET-request. Upon receiving the GET-request you check the validity of the user owning the comment:

```
SELECT ownerid FROM messages WHERE id = $_GET['id']
```

(Though, make sure to protect yourself from mysql injection (using PDO), the above example is NOT safe).

Comment: Yeah I know, my example uses PDO(hope that's valid).

Comment: That's valid! You're like the first person on SO using pdo instead of mysql_injection.. Congratz!

Comment: Yay, thanks :D. Just one more question, I do the GET request with javascript, or is there another way?

Comment: AJAX is a great way to solve this if you want your website to be dynamic. When I create ajax request, I make sure that non-javascript browsers still have a fallback.